# Long Polling não faz o GET do timestamp

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

**Peguei esse exemplo no blog http://rberaldo.com.br/server-push-long-polling-php-ios/**

Server.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require 'pdo.php';
set_time_limit(0);
while ( true )
{
    $requestedTimestamp = isset( $_GET['timestamp'] ) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : 0;

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM publication WHERE publication_time = :requestedTimestamp" );

    $stmt->bindParam( ':requestedTimestamp', $requestedTimestamp );
    $stmt->execute();



    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    while ($rowpublication = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $publication_id  = $rowpublication['publication_id'];
    }
        $json = json_encode( $publication_id );
        echo $json;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sleep( 2 );
        continue;
    }
}
?>
```

Client.js

```
function getContent( timestamp )
{
    var queryString = { 'timestamp' : timestamp };

    $.get ( '/php-long-polling-master/server/server.php' , queryString , function ( data )
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $( '#response' ).html( obj.content );

        // reconecta ao receber uma resposta do servidor
        getContent( obj.timestamp );
    });
}

$( document ).ready ( function ()
{
    getContent();
});
```

> ELE NÃO FAZ O ISSET DO TIMESTAMP, ONDE ESTÁ O PROBLEMA?

Answer (score 0):

Se você está tentando pegar o `timestamp` através da resposta data ao `$.getJSON`, então por que você não respondeu com o `timestamp`?

O trecho correto da resposta do seu código deveria ser:

```
 $json = json_encode(array(
     'content' => $publication_id, 
     'timestamp' => $requestedTimestamp
));
```

Não sei de onde vem o `content` no seu código (aparentemente você não retorna nenhum dado com esse nome) então defini ele como o `$publication_id`.

Comment: Ai que esta o problema,if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0), se o resultado da query nao for encontrada, então vai continuar o loop sem a timestamp

Comment: Aí você tem que mudar a lógica do front-end, caso não for obtido uma resposta